# Iterating over a column in Big query

Tags: sql, loops, google-bigquery, iteration

I am using Big query to extract results from employee learning table. I need to figure out if an employee has completed a set of courses for a department. For example if an employee complete all of these three courses say, course 100, course 200 and course 300, they can be classified as as compliant else They are non-compliant. I have created a dummy example of how my data is structured, unfortunately due to organization policy I cant share more information.

```
Employee course 
1        100 
1        101 
1        200 
1        300
1        300 
1        400 
2        100 
2        200
3        100
3        200
3        300
4        75
4        85
4        95
4        105 
4        115
4        125  
5        200
5        200
5        100
5        100
5        100
5        300
5        300
6        100
7        100
8        300
8        200
8        100
8        101
8        102
9        100
9        200
9        300
```

My initial thoughts are to create columns with 1 and 0 say using case statement if course id 100 then 1 else 0 and try to sum to three new created columns by at employee level. any suggestion would be welcome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use below simple approach

```
select Employee, array_length(array_agg(distinct course)) = 3 isCompliant
from your_table
where course in (100, 200, 300)
group by Employee
```

if applied to sample data in your question - output is

[image]

The better option is

```
select Employee, 
  ifnull(array_length(split(string_agg(distinct if(course in (100, 200, 300), '' || course, null)))), 0) = 3 isCompliant,
from your_table
group by Employee
```

with [what appears like better] output :o)

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Let me add more complexity to it and i will change my question too.

Say employee who has completed course 100,200,300 They are compliant in Bakery 
Employee who has completed course 75,85,95 They are compliant in Grocery
Employee who has completed 101 and 102 They are compliant in Nighfill. 

I have five more validation other combination of courses here and keen on repeating once i can get couple of them working.

Comment: This is considered a bad taste here on SO to change your question after you got an answer on it! At least because this invalidates that answer! if you have new question - just post new one and I/we will be happy to help further (obviously don't forget to show your efforts as we are not her to write queries for you - we are here to HELP you in your efforts!). Read also [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Comment: Note: I reversed your question to original version!

Comment: oh okay sorry i wasnt aware about rules, as you can see I am new here. I will put in a new question.

Comment: meantime, have you tried proposed solution? does it work for you (in terms of original question obviously)?